# Maximum event interceptions

Tags: algorithm, events, overlap

I'm trying to figure out an algorithm that will detect the maximum number of intersections of events over time. The following picture will explain the situation.

I have multiple events that can overlap and I have to determine what is the maximum overlap among all the events.

**What I know?**

I know **event ID**, **start time** and **end time**. I also have **coordinates**.

**What is maximum event overlap?**

In this case showed in picture, the maximum is **3**. This is because at one time there are only 3 events that are overlapping. E.g ID's: `1,3,4` or `1,3,5`.

[image: Events in time]

I have a solution that requires a lot of cycles. But I can't figure out some fast elegant solution suitable for a web application with many events.

Thank you for all your answers in advance. If you find some grammar mistakes, please edit the post. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide us with your code? Maybe we can work on the existing code and help to improve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sweep line algorithm. Here's how it should work in your case:

1- Create a vector called `sweep`.

2- Split every event into two events:

- **(start time, 1)**: the **1** here is to denote that the first part denotes the start time.
- **(end time, -1)**: the **-1** here is to denote that the first part denotes the end time.

3- Insert the new events into the vector `sweep`.

4- Sort the created vector in increasing order of the first part, in case of a tie in the increasing order of the second part.

5- Now the following pseudo code should answer your question:

```
int answer = 0, eventsCount = 0;
for(int i = 0 -> sweep.size()){
    eventsCount += sweep[i].second;
    answer = max(answer, eventsCount);
}
```

Here `eventsCount` denotes the number of opened events at the current time, while `answer` denotes the best answer you have so far. At the end the answer to your problem will be found in the variable `answer`.